# Passing Crystal Report name as parameter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

**I am using a function which is calling a crystal report as :**

ShowReport ( Report1)

**In show report ShowReport :**

```
Dim repDoc As New Report1  **' here i am want to assign crytalReport name**
repDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "*****")
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = repDoc
CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: do you mean report file name i.e. filename.rpt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this in the past that you may be able to use for your purposes. Normaly I use a Dropdown list or a Listbox to allow the user to select the file they want to view and then use pass the Item Index to the the intFileId.

```
Private Sub OpenCR(ByVal intfileId As Integer)
    Dim aReport As ReportDocument
    Select Case intfileId
        Case 0 : aReport = New CountSheets
        Case 1 : aReport = New CategoryVariance
        Case 2 : aReport = New DollarVariance
        Case 3 : aReport = New CategoryVarianceAdmin
        Case 4 : aReport = New DollarVarianceAdmin
        Case 5 : aReport = New PhysicalCount
        Case 6 : aReport = New BookToPhysicalCount
        Case 7 : aReport = New MissingItemCodes
    End Select

    aReport.Refresh()
    aReport.SetParameterValue("isAmtsShown", isAmtsShown)
    aReport.SetParameterValue("parStoreID", StoreID)
    aReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password", "server", "table")
    crvReports.ReportSource = aReport

End Sub
```

To answer the specific question about passing the name as the argument. You could do it with something like this:

```
 Private Sub RunReportbyName()
    ' The Crystal Report name in
    ' this project is MyReport.rpt
    Dim aReport As ReportDocument = New MyReport
    OpenCR(aReport)
End Sub

Private Sub OpenCR(ByVal RepDoc As ReportDocument)
    'RepDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("","","","")
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RepDoc
    CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = True

End Sub
```